# Windows Mobile: automatically copy files on reboot

Tags: java, c++, windows, windows-mobile

I have a Java app that runs on a Windows mobile device.  At startup the app talks to our server to see if any files need updating and downloads them if they do.  If any of the files are dlls they need to be stored in a temp directory and the device is rebooted because they might be currently in use.  When the app starts it reads an xml file that lists all of the temp files and where they need to go and copies them into place.

A new requirement has come up that involves also updating the JVM files as part of this process.  Since the code that does the copying is run on the JVM there is no way to do it since the files will always be in use.  So we are looking at writing something in native code to do this copying process.

Before we start, I was just wondering if anyone knew of an already existing application or technique that does this (someone suggested a registry entry that tells the device to copy files on startup for example).  Basically the requirement is to read some sort of configuration file that details the location of the source file and the destination then performs the copy.  Any ideas before I reinvent the wheel by writing an app myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of another answer, I have written a simple app to do it and put it in the startup directory.  Was pretty easy, just didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

If your target handsets are handheld barcode scanners (Symbol, Intermec, etc.) they already have a framework in place for this.  I don't have all the details, but I know from previous projects that they have a "protected" memory location that allows application to essentially re-configure / copy themselves from hard boots and similar problems.  It might be worth seeing if any of that would work on your existing targets.

The scanners use either Windows CE or Windows Mobile.

Comment: The target devices are standard PDAs running Windows Mobile. (HTC HD2, HTC P6500 for example)

Answer (score 0):

You can also rename your running executable file by the running-application itself. After this you can copy the file into the directory and simply restart your application.